# How to avoid paying for musical gardens if visiting Versailles Palace on a Tuesday?

Tags: budget, paris, tips-and-tricks, parks-and-gardens, versailles

We plan to visit Versailles Palace on May-8-2012, which is a Tuesday. Unfortunately [the official website](http://en.chateauversailles.fr/prepare-my-visit-/single/tickets-and-rates/billets-et-tarifs/les-grandes-eaux-1-en) states that the garden is not free for entrance on that Tuesday as the  musical garden would be running that day. Anyone know if there is any gate/backdoor to the garden without having to pay 8.50 Euro for the music?

Comment: FYI, May 8 is a holiday in France. I think the palace will be open at the usual time, perhaps more crowded (but that would go for any other tourist attraction).

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of tricks to getting in faster or cheaper normally.  However, all bets are really off with an event - there's likely security at all gates, and they'll know them better than us.

- If you are under 26 (EU only) or with a EU student visa over 6 months, you can skip the long queue and proceed directly to the 'A' entrance with your student card and your passport
- Normally, if you have young children, access to the grounds is free. If visiting with kids, it might be worth trying to press your luck saying that you just want to see the gardens, and don't want to pay for the whole group
- One final trick - it is often free to access the park from the Rue de la Paroisse entrance (leads to the Bassin de Neptune), or if you are walking, from the Boulevard de la Reine (next to the four-star hotel Trianon Palace).   You may find these entrances available as an 'option' - or at the least an alternative to try and persuade the friendly staff member to let you in as 'you're only here for the day and you've come so far' etc :)

Comment: The entrance next to Rue de la Paroisse is mostly closed. I bike there everyday and I do not remember seeing it open (even though there is indeed an entrance). There was a moment when it was open but that was for some spectacles taking pace next to the Bassin de Neptune (you had to pay to enter anyway).

Answer (score 4):

During may to september, the garden is free open only during few hour due to the musical animation. You have to visit garden before 11 AM or after 17 PM. 
If you are moderate walker, you could enter also by Saint-Cyr road. You arrive by the "grand canal" the main basin.